# Connector not found 404 Bad Request

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Kafka connect APIs to get the config of the kafka connector.
endpoint: connectors/test-connector-abc
Method: GET

I am 404 Bad request and the config of the connector alternatively. What could be the reason behind this ?

Also, for endpoint: connectors/test-connector-abc/status
Method: GET

1. I am getting 404 as response i.e. connector not found
2. connector with status of connector and task as running another
3. connector with status of connector as running and task as failed but with different worker Ids as in response 2
   all these responses alternatively for the same connector when the curl is hit in interval of seconds.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Please share the full HTTP request and response you are seeing (use curl or something similar).

Comment: Are you running a cluster of connectors? You might run into similar issues when the `listeners`/`rest.advertised.listener` configs are not set properly between individual workers, in that the server may accept the request, but cannot coordinate with other workers upon status/configs